# El SDK actual no permite el destino .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, json

Consulto en este foro si alguien puede ayudarme a la solución de este problema. Estoy usando las herramientas para construir app de Teams en Visual Studio 2019. Me sale un mensaje de error. Ya intenté solucionarlo creando un archivo global.json para definer el SDK que quiero usar pero no resultó. Adjunto el mensaje abajo.  Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por responder. La versión que tengo de Visual Studio es la que muestro en pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y los SDK instalados y los runtimes son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Gracias por responder Vlorz.

La versión de mi Visual Studio 2019 es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muestro a continuación Los SDK y los runtimes instalados en mi máquina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esperando nuevamente de su ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas que *Visual Studio* esté actualizado a una versión que soporte el **.Net Core** que quieres utilizar.

Para **.Net Core 3.1** necesitas la versión **16.5** o superior de *Visual Studio*. También te tienes que instalar el **SDK** de **.Net Core 3.1**.

El **SDK** lo puedes descargar desde https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1.

Si actualizas *Visual Studio* a la versión **16.7** o superior el **SDK** vendrá incluido.

La versión **16.9** te soporta los **.Net Core** hasta la versión **5.0**. Si quieres experimentar con el **.Net Core 6.0** deberás instalar la versión *preview* *Visual Studio* **16.10**.